# What causes the magnetic field around a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, maxwell-equations

According to maxwell’s equations, a magnetic field is caused by a changing electric field, but where is this changing electric field in the context of a current carrying conductor that has an induced magnetic field around it?

And if there isn’t a changing electric field, what causes the magnetic field to appear?[image]

Comment: *I studied that according to maxwells equation changing electric field produces magnetic field...* This doesn't mean this is the only way to have a magnetic field... You can have static magnetic fields without any changing electric fields.

Comment: This seems to be an already-answered question <https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64703> and others

Comment: You seem to be forgetting the $\bf J$ term in $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0\left(\mathbf{J} + \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t} \right)$.