# Is magnetism caused by effect of relativity on interaction between moving charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, relativity

I have heard that cause of magnetism is easily amswered by relativity ? Is it true ?  If then how can  we explain cause of  Fleming's left and right hand rules ?

Comment: What we usually call electric field and magnetic field are components of geometric object called Faraday tensor.  The object itself is independent of the observer but the components are.
This is well explained in this lecture  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFAxSEoj6Go&list=PLMsYJgjgZE8hh6d6ia2dP1NI0BKNRXbiw&index=14&t=0s

Comment: Welcome to SE!  See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63009/relativistic-origin-of-magnetic-field and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64703/how-special-relativity-causes-magnetism.