# Why does inter-electron distance in wire grow with acceleration?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

When you have an electrically neutral wire, and apply a voltage across it, free electrons (provided by source) flow through the wire and thus an electric current is created. Assuming an ideal scenario, there will be no electrostatic force generated in a stationary frame since the net charge density remains unchanged. **My question is, why is this so?** The accepted answer from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63534/there-must-be-free-positive-charges-moving-oppositely-to-electrons-for-the-wire?rq=1) says the following,

> *"... inter-electron distances expand as they are accelerated. This expansion exactly compensates the Einstein contraction so that inter-electrons distances do not change in the lab frame and wire sustains neutrality."*

I don't understand why this is so. Could you provide me with a reference on a discussion of this? Or maybe you could put a quick, or long, derivation/discussion below?

Comment: Note that the question was answered by the questioner (who accepted the answer).